# convert some records to comma separated array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have table like this:

```
table Database
+------+--------------+
| name | data         |
+------+--------------+
| foo  | certaindata1 |
| bar  | certaindata2 |
| foo  | certaindata3 |
+------+--------------+
```

and I want to output data for array values like:
`array('certaindata1','certaindata2','certaindata3')`

I have try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM Database");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     echo $row['data'];
}
```

and result is `certaindata1certaindata2certaindata3`
where array value should be `'certaindata1','certaindata2','certaindata3'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is expected. You're simply echoing `$row['data'];` without any spaces or newlines -- so the result will be `certaindata1certaindata2certaindata3`.  If you want to store the results in an array, you can do the following:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $yourArray[] = $row['data']; //storing the $row['data'] in an array
}
$comma_separated = implode(',', $yourArray);
print_r($comma_separated);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: please edit to print_r($comma_separated); no need echo again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use implode() to make it comma separated..

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $yourArray[] = $row['data']; //storing the $row['data'] in an array
}
$result = implode(",", $yourArray);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is a copy of my answer.

Comment: see the difference in time. how can i see if you edit it 9 seconds earlier than me?